# Как выключить перезапуск приложения при краше? (Xiaomi)

Tags: android, android-studio

Собственно, если происходит краш приложения, то оно перезапускается, все логи теряются, но если второй раз сделать краш, то уже крашится окончательно. Как выключить это поведение, чтобы не перезапускало, а вылетало сразу?

Comment: У вас, возможно, не одна активити на всё приложение? Коли так, то, возможно, если она будет одна, то проблема исчезнет. Если актвити лишние не убрать то, возможно, поможет включение `don't keep activities` в настройках разработчика. И/или попробовать другой девайс, т.к. проблема может быть результатом изменения в ОС со стороны производителя.

Answer (score 1):

android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"

Обычно это не приносит неудобств, вы можете увидеть в Logсat среди приложений запущенных в Debug следующее: `[com.name.app](DEAD)` В нем хранятся логи сессии, которая закончилась вылетом.

Также вы можете перехватить краш:

```
public class App extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
                    // выполните необходимые действия или запустите желаемую активити 
                }
            });
}}
```

Будьте осторожны, добавление setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler часто приводит к утечкам памяти, не используйте это в продакшене

Comment: в Logcat е показывается ошибка на долю секунды, а потом сразу всё очищается и начинаются логи перезапущенного приложения. Не очень понял про android:clearTaskOnLaunch, в любом случае не думаю, что тут помогут какие-то флаги активити. И не думаю что setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler подойдёт. Мне нужно, чтобы приложение падало с первого раза, а не второго, setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler никак с этим не помогает, а использовать его для лога ошибки больше как костыль выглядит

Comment: @IR42 В списке приложений Logcat будет ваше вылетевшее приложение с меткой (DEAD), там все ваши логи. Все пропадает потому что запускается новое приложение, просто откройте то которое (DEAD). Поведение с перезапуском изменить нельзя, оно появилось ориентировочно с пятого андроида. setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler я вам посоветовал, как возможность не вылетать и не терять логи (но они не потеряны). Можете например там поставить breakepoint

Comment: да, есть dead, но там пустой лог после краша, а саму ошибку видно в окне рабочего аппа на долю секунды и потом оно очищается и начинаются логи перезапущенного, почему-то так работает

Comment: @IR42 первый запуск logcat бывает кривым, его нужно перезапускать и поклацать приложения или устройства. Сообщите пожалуйста если найдете решение